# Segmentation fault when "reallocating" new memory for 2D array C

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, malloc

I am having hard time reallocating memory for my 2D array. I get segmentation fault, whenever I try to modify the already reallocated array after that. My code is working for the default sizes of the array, only when I reallocate with `grow`, it gets stuck. Do you see why?

Furthermore, what is the most atomic and short way of reallocating 2D-array that you know? What is generally a good practice when doing so?

Here is the code:

```
void grow(int **arr, int size_r, int size_c, int newsize_r, int newsize_c)
{
    int **newarr = (int **)malloc((size_t)newsize_r * sizeof(int *));

    for (int i = 0; i < newsize_r; ++i) {
        newarr[i] = (int *)malloc((size_t)newsize_c * sizeof(int));
        if (i < size_r) {
            memcpy(newarr[i], arr[i], (size_t) size_c * sizeof(int));
            free(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    free(arr);
    arr = newarr;
}
```

I get for the address of `arr` `0x7fff88fbd338` and for `newarr`: `0x7fff88fbd348` respectively.

I use it here, `read` reads stdin and stores every line in the 2D array.

```
int read(int **s, int count, int size, int len) {
    int c, i = 0, j;
    int temp = size; //1d
    int temp2 = len; //2d

    for (j = 0; j < temp; j++) {
        s[j][len - 1] = -1; /* sentinel */
    }

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (count == temp) {
            /* realloc 1D */
            grow(s, temp, temp2, 2 * temp, temp2);
            temp = 2 * temp;
            if (!s) { /*check*/ }
            for (j = count + 1; j < temp; j++) {
                /* first here segmentation fault */
                s[j][temp2 - 1] = -1;
            }
        }
        if (s[count][i] == -1) {
            /* realloc 2D */
            grow(s, temp, temp2, temp, 2 * temp2);
            temp2 = 2 * temp2;
            for (j = count + 1; j < temp; j++)
                s[j][temp2 - 1] = -1;
            if (!s[count]) { /*check*/ }
        }
        /* more code, irrelevant here */
    }
}
```

Is also the use of a sentinel `-1` proper? If not why?

Moreover, if you have some other general remarks about style, format etc., I would be glad to see them.

Comment: What is the backtrace for the segmentation fault, when you run it under a debugger?

Comment: it is either in the for loop after calling `grow` or when there is not such loop at the next place available - when tries to write data to newly allocated memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass `arr` by reference in your `grow` function. Currently you are modifying a local variable at the end of your function. This assignment will not be seen outside of your function, causing the code there to still use the old pointer. You freed the memory this pointer points to in your function, which is causing your undefined behavior. You could easily solve this by passing your array by reference (another pointer to it):

```
void grow(int ***arr, int size_r, int size_c, int newsize_r, int newsize_c)
{
    int **newarr = (int **)malloc((size_t)newsize_r * sizeof(int *));
    for (int i = 0; i < newsize_r; ++i) {
        newarr[i] = (int *)malloc((size_t)newsize_c * sizeof(int));
        if (i < size_r) {
            memcpy(newarr[i], (*arr)[i], (size_t) size_c * sizeof(int));
            free((*arr)[i]);
        }
    }
    free(*arr);
    *arr = newarr;
}
```

Then in your code, pass the address of the array to the function:

```
grow(&s, /*Other parameters*/);
```

Comment: Yes, this code does the same as your original function, but now the variable arr will be passed by reference, that way the value will be changed outside of the function.

Comment: Memory leak: the individual rows of the old `arr` matrix are not freed.  Also note that the reallocated matrix is partially uninitialized.

Comment: If I'm correct, the individual rows are still freed using the call to free from within the loop. You are right about the values being partially uninitialized, but the uninitialized values are only in the part of the array that was outside the original array. These values will be initialized in the calling function if I read the question code correctly (comparable to a real realloc).

Comment: @Shadowwolf: you are correct for the case where `newsize_r  > size_r`, which the name `grow` probably implies, but if the matrix is actually resized to a smaller size, in a later iteration of the code, the lines beyond the new row size would be lost.  Regarding the partially uninitialized array, the cost of `calloc()` is negligible and buys a consistent zero value for all newly allocated matrix cells.

Comment: You're right about that case, I missed the case where `newsize_r > size_r`. Although in the example usage of the function in the original code, we can see that `newsize_r` will always be larger than `size_r`. But indeed, you are right about that case.